# TensorFlow Object Detection API error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, object-detection

I am using Tensorflow Object Detection API to train my own object detector. After preparing everything needed: I put `data/train.record, test.record`, `training/object-detection.pbtxt, faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_pets.config` into the folder of `object_detection`. Run

`python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir = training/ --pipeline_config_path = training/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_pets.config`

**I got error:**

```
`
username@host:~/Documents/tensorflowModels/object_detection$ python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir = training/ --pipeline_config_path = training/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_pets.config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 198, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "train.py", line 143, in main
    model_config, train_config, input_config = get_configs_from_pipeline_file()
  File "train.py", line 103, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    text_format.Merge(f.read(), pipeline_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 118, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 78, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: =`
```

Any idea what is wrong in the process?

Comment: Did you append the direcotries ´tensorflow/models´ and ´tensorflow/models/slim´ to your PYTHONPATH Environment Variable? If so, try launching your command without spaces in front and after the "="s.

Comment: @ITiger, Thank you very much! I did have appended the direcotries ´tensorflow/models´ and ´tensorflow/models/slim´ before running. Surprisingly, after removing spaces before and after the "=", it runs. Why is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summerize my comment:

- Remove the spaces in front and behind the equal sign. The spaces cause the argument parser of Tensorflow (which is based on the argparse module) to parse the '=' as argument, which is obviously wrong. You can see this confusion in the error message:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: =`